# How to setup VSCode intellisense for Protobuf-generated JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers

Normally my VSCode installation provides intellisense hints in my Javascript projects. However, I'm having problems getting VSCode to display/register intellisense for message types imported from another JavaScript file which was generated through the protocol buffer compiler `protoc`.

Below is a screenshot of the problem I'm facing. Based on the protobuf file added below, I expect functions of `setId()`, `setName()`, `setSalary()` on the `jeff` object. However, VSCode does not seem to recognize the `Schema.Employee` type.

[image: VSCode not providing intellisense]

Is there anything I can do to have intellisense work with types which were generated from protocol-buffers?

[reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Tested using VSCode 1.50.1 and protoc version `libprotoc 3.13.0`:

I compiled the following protobuf file using

```
protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. employees.proto
```

which generates `employees_pb.js`

employees.proto

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

option optimize_for = SPEED;

message Employee {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    float salary = 3;
}

message Employees {
    repeated Employee employees = 1;
}
```

index.js:

```js
// import schema from compiled file
const Schema = require("./employees_pb");

//create a new instance of Employee
const jeff = new Schema.Employee();
jeff.setId(1001); // <-- Intellisense does not work here.
jeff.setName("Jeff");
jeff.setSalary(1001);
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "protobuff",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "google-protobuf": "^3.13.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `employees_pb` file, you can change the last line to get full intellisense:

```js
module.exports = {...goog, ...proto};
// goog.object.extend(exports, proto);
```

For some reason the exports extension doesn't work? I opened up this [issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/8389) on the topic.